# How to download a file using requests

Tags: python, download, python-requests, zip

I am using the requests library to download a file from a URL. This is my code

```
for tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    if '.zip' in str(tag):
        file_name = str(tag).strip().split('>')[-2].split('<')[0]
        link = link_name+tag.get('href')
        r = requests.get(link, stream=True)

        with open(os.path.join(download_path, file_name), 'wb') as fd:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                if chunk:
                    fd.write(chunk)
```

And then I unzip the file using this code

```
unzip_path = os.path.join(download_path, file_name.split('.')[0])

with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(download_path, file_name), 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(unzip_path)
```

This code looks if there is a zip file in the provided page and then downloads the zipped file in a directory. Then it will unzip the file using the `zipFile` library.

The problem with this code is that sometimes the download is not complete. So for example if the zipped file is 312KB long only parts of it is downloaded. And then I get a `BadZipFile` error. But sometimes the entire file is downloaded correctly.

I tried the same without streaming and even that results in the same problem.

How do I check if all the chunks are downloaded properly.

Comment: Can you consider the sleep function from time module in order to make the programe sleep couple of seconds so the file gets downloaded completely before moving the to the extraction part ?

Comment: @AmineBTG  tried adding `time.sleep(5)` before the unzip_path. But that does not seem to solve the problem. Should I add the sleep inside `for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):`?

Comment: Try to get your file without stream `stream=False` and write to the file without chunks `fd.write(r.content)`

Comment: Ok. why do you write chunks ? Why don't write the entire file in one go once the request is recieved (stream = False) ?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```py
import requests

url = '...'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open('data.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=16*1024):
        f.write(chunk)
f.close()
```

Comment: BTW, `f` will be closed automatically when using `with`, so `f.close()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works:

```
r = requests.get(link)  
with open(os.path.join(download_path, file_name), 'wb') as fd:
    fd.write(r.content)
```

Comment: This too doesn't seem to work all the time. I have a `time.sleep(5)` before the unzip_path now. It only downloads 5Kb of the entire 315KB

Comment: Check return code. Is 200? `r.status_code`

Comment: sometimes it is 200 and sometimes it is 403.

Comment: If there is no privacy concerns, could you post few urls as example, please?